# Importing and playing swf files in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

1. Does anyone have any sample code on how to take an swf, import it into FlashDevelop and play it? I'm working solely with FlashDevelop and need to know this.
2. What programs can you create swfs with apart from Adobe Flash CS5/6. I need a free program to create them. If that isn't possible other free workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read about "Embedding asset types" here: [Embedding asset types](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html) , especially "Embedding SWF files" part.
2. What do you mean by "create swfs"? Creating of vector animations and graphics? If yes so check this out: [Synfig Studio](http://www.synfig.org/cms/)